# Cant stop input from displaying auto-fill details in Chrome

Tags: html

I have an `input` on my website which whenever i click in it displays the following

[image]

I have the following `HTML` for the `input`

```
        <div id="searchFieldSectionDiv" class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%">
                <label class="sr-only" for="searchField">Filter results</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <!-- TODO: Need to filter products section as the user types -->
                    <input id="searchField" class="form-control" placeholder="Type to search..." autocomplete="off">
                    <span id="searchclear" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="fas fa-search" style="margin-right: 0px"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have tried adding `type="search` but it still displays the address box.

Not to sure on how to hide it,  all other browsers seem fine, just Chrome.

Ideally i want to add this at top level so i dont have to keep adding this to every `input` but again not too sure which level to add it too (`body` maybe?)

Comment: what is the rest of your html?

Comment: @xmastertje updated `HTML`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill) works

Comment: Is the problem that the box appears, or that it shows previous fields?

Comment: I read that this should work `autocomplete="something-new"` Or something Chrome doesn't understand like `autocomplete="disabled"`

Comment: @xmastertje Can you suggest your last comment as an answer. I did read this also but i honestly thought it would cause issues on other browsers but it doesn't.  As for the 'this' link, i read that post prior to posting this and it didn't work

Comment: Did you tried `autocomplete="off" ` ?

Comment: @murday1983 I posted my answer I hope it is good like this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `autocomplete="off"` to `autocomplete="disabled"`

Chrome stopped supporting `autocomplete="off"` that's why it isn't working but it doesn't understand if you use `autocomplete="disabled"` that's why this works for now